# Call change event in IE8 on <input file> programmaticaly

Tags: jquery, file-io, primefaces, internet-explorer-8

Primefaces 5

I have `<input type="file" class="ui-fileupload-choose>` in code to upload the files. This `input`-Tag is generated automatically from a PrimeFaces component `<p:fileUpload>`. 
I want to hide the button for `input` element and use my own styled button for upload.

So this is the styled button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#formId\\:uploaderId .ui-fileupload-choose input').click();">
```

This does function in FF, Chrome and IE9, 10, 11. 
But in IE8 nothing happens in upload phase. The "choose file" dialog is shown. The generated `input file` has JQuery change event. I believe that this event will not be called, because if I click on `input file` button it goes in all browsers.

I've tried

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#formId\\:uploaderId .ui-fileupload-choose input').click(); #formId\\:uploaderId ui-fileupload-choose input').trigger('change');">
```

but it doesn't help.

Also I've tried

```
$('#formId\\:uploaderId .ui-fileupload-choose input').change(function () {
    // Cause the change() event
    // to be fired in IE8 et. al.
    //some checks against recursion.
     alert("I'm in change");
    $('#formId\\:uploaderId .ui-fileupload-choose input').change();               
});
```

The function in change is called but it doesn't help either.

What can I do in this situation ?

Comment: Magically I'm working on the same problem now in one of my projects.
It seems that it's a security issue, where the click/change of the input file is being triggered manually by javascript onclick. The process of initiating the upload is taking a place but the request is never being sent! I'll update this question if I find some elegant solution! currently I'm checking for the browser version, if it's IE I'm changing the way the upload is done.

Comment: @HatemAlimam Cool, thank you for your comment.   I will use the `<p:fileUpload>` without changes if there is no simple solution to this problem. Good luck !

Comment: I just found another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556988/ie-doesnt-allow-to-upload-the-file-if-it-is-not-keybord-click-for-input-type-f) on that topic, I think I was right it's a security thing for IE :(

Comment: I found this answer interesting and as you say it has something to do with security.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13994676/2023524)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a security restriction in IE.

When there's `<input type="file"/>` which has *either* of

- `display:none`
- `visbilty:hidden`
- `opacity: 0`

IE blocks the request to upload the file if it's being called manually (javascript click).

In PrimeFaces case the input file has `opacity: 0`.

Here's how the input file looks like without the CSS extra flavours:

[image: fileupload]

The work around is to move that input file outside `p:fileUpload` component so it can loose the CSS roles, and append it to a span or div with button styling, that would result an actual click on the file input.

*Button*

```
<span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
   <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload File
</span>
```

---

*javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ui-fileupload-buttonbar span input[type=file]').addClass('uploadBtn');
   $('.btn-file').append($('.uploadBtn'));
});
```

Something link this:

[image: append1]

Now to get it to look nice and work in the same time on all browsers including IE, some CSS should be added.
First ignore the first two CSS classes `btn btn-primary` (colors, padding etc..)

The `btn-file` is the custom trick:

```css
.btn-file {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 .btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 999px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;        
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
 }
```

The final result is a button with input file in the background:

[image: final]

The `p:fileUpload` component should be hidden:

```
<p:fileUpload style="display: none" />
```

---

In order to display the error messages you can use onchange event for that input file:

```
$('.uploadBtn').change(function() {
   var a = $('.ui-fileupload-content').html(); var b = $('#editUserUploadMessages').html(a);
})
```

Where `#editUserUploadMessages` is a div containing all the messages.

Finally hide the other uploaded files:

```css
#editUserUploadMessages .ui-fileupload-files {
     display: none;
}
```

You can find a small example on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/primeStyleUpload/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml) and a [Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/primeStyleUpload/)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer. I need also errors as (fileSize and fileType) to be shown, so I posted additional solution.

Comment: I have added also a way to show the messages, retry the demo, upload a non image file :)

Answer (score 1):

Additional solution to an excellent answer of Hatem. 
It is using this  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994676/2023524).

You can use html tag `<label>` to forward the click to input buton.

```
<h:form id="formId" >
 <style>

 #formId\:uploaderId .ui-fileupload-buttonbar {
    position: absolute;  
    left: -10000px;
 }

 #formId\:uploaderId .ui-fileupload-content {
    border: none;
 }
 </style>

 <p:fileUpload id="uploaderId" mode="advanced" auto="true" allowTypes="..." fileLimit="...">


 <label for="formId:uploaderId_input">
    <span class="fa fa-upload" />    
 </label>
</h:form>
```

This way the errors will be shown at point where `<p:fileUpload>` is included.

Answer (score -2):

1. add style display:none to input type="file"
2. create new text box and button at the position of input type file
3. create js function when click your button that click the button of file upload

Comment: Please don't answer a question without reading it carefully first!